# bootstrap navbar search splitting in IE11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

The issue I am experiencing is that in IE11, the submit button for my form is appearing below the search form itself. I have tried various recommended fixes and yet none of them have corrected the issue. In Opera and Chrome the form presents correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();
            }, function() {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp()
            });
        });
    </script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
        .navbar-nav > li {
                    float: left;
                }

        navbar-form .input-group-btn,
        .navbar-form .input-group-addon {
                    width: auto;
                }
    </style>            
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Example</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Example<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Press Releases</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Library in the News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blogs</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sign up for our newsletter</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>   
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Online Resources<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Zinio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Transparent Languages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Chiltons</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3-M Cloud EBooks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">OneClick</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">GALE Virtual Library</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Interlibrary Loan</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form pull-right" action="http://example.org/eg/opac/results" method="get">
                <div class="form-group" style="width:auto">
                    <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Catalog" maxlength="200" size="20" name="query" style="max-width:200px" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="qtype" value="keyword" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="locg" value="365" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="search">Search</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pts6s9hw/)

Comment: If you have tried a few fixes, you should share them in your question to prevent other people from recommending things you've already tried.

Comment: well the first thing I see is that "pull-right" is being used on the navbar, that is not used as of Boostrap 3, please read the docs: navbar-right, navbar-left, navbar-text, and navbar-form

Comment: Thanks. I found the issue and now have the bar working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box Bootstrap deals with wrapping issue by adding a classes to the header section that allows the navigation to collapse into a the button menu to help support mobile devices and smaller borwser resolutions. If you add these classes back in the DIV you will no longer get the wrapping issue you are seeing in IE (and in Chrome). Did you remove these classes on purpose?

Here is a sample of the updated code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Example</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"> <!--Add these classes here-->
```

You can see the updated [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pts6s9hw/1/).

Comment: That seems to have worked. I accidentally deleted those classes out of the posted tag, but I discovered a missing close tag in them that was causing the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear @slink, glad that worked out. Make sure to accept the answer if it solved your problem so if anyone else comes across this post in the future they will know what the solution was.